# Need Whatsapp api for sending messages from my PHP project

Tags: whatsapp, php-5.6

i want to know if there is any whatsapp api that can help me to send messages from my php project because after some research i found that whatsapp doesn't have any api for developers..
someone can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

## I used Google :

A quick google search with the proceeding query : "WhatsApp PHP API" gives us many results , the [first result](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API) is a github page made by [mgp25](https://github.com/mgp25) a well known member of the github dev community. 
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right that whatsapp does not published the api for the such chatting using php .
By the way you can use the sharing uri to share text messages who have whats appp installed in their device or web chat option for whatsapp

```
   Chat API:  https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=15551234567
   Custom URL: Scheme  whatsapp://send?text=hello world
```

First one is used to open chat with the desired phone number and the second one is used to share some test as custom url format.

Comment: Is it possible to send message directly without confirm button?

Answer (score 0):

Whatsapp is now maintain by facebook and it has created a api for business to communicate with customers .
This it has launched api for whatsapp as well as for Facebook instagram .
You can have a look on the documentation portal for whatsapp api for more details

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/reference

Also there are partners of Facebook who give ready made solution to the productivity.